# Redirect subfolder to Wordpress without showing URL

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a PHP Laravel application hosted at xyx.com. Now I am setting up a blog for my application at xyz.com/blog. This blog I want to host at Wordpress.com so that my blog is managed by Wordpress for me.

> xyz.com/blog -> xyz.wordpress.com

I tried to setup some redirect in the Routes -

```
Route::get('blog/{whatever?}', function($whatever = null) {
    $myurl = "https://xyz.wordpress.com/".$whatever;    
    return Redirect::to($myurl);

});
```

But now the Wordpress URL is visible to any visitor. How do I redirect it such a way that the URL that the visitor sees is xyz.com and not wordpress.com?

I do not wish to use IFRAMES as they have SEO disadvantage. I also do not wish to download the pagecontent from Wordpress on the serverside and serve the content as it will be slow.

Comment: That's just not possible in any way that makes sense. If you're blog is on `wordpress.com` then this domain will show up in the address bar. However I think you can choose a custom domain at wordpress.com and then redirect to that...

Comment: Only way I see this working is using an evil `iframe`. D:

Comment: Imagine linking to a login form from your site and displaying paypal's login URL in the browser. Does that sound like something that should be possible ? :)

Comment: if i am redirected to an url, i demand to see that url.... otherwise won't that be security violation in end users aspect?

Comment: Can I use a proxy server like NGINX to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a subdomain and map it to wordpress.com (see: https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-subdomain/).

Instead of having `xyz.com/blog` you'll have `blog.xyz.com` and everything will be fine.